# Can't paste javascript commands into addressbar (ie10)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I can't seem to find the answer on Google,
When pasting `javascript: bla bla bla` into the address bar, the `javascript:` part gets removed automatically.

I tried a work-around by having my macro-robot type out the `javascript:` manually, but the code still doesn't get executed. I assume it's some sort of a security feature.

Any idea on how to disable it?

Thanks

Comment: Use the console instead.

Answer (score 4):

Copying/pasting disabled for the security reason. You still have 2 choices though - either type it manually (it still works) or add "javascript:" link as a bookmark.

Comment: That's a very poor decision. Still happens in IE11 - any Microsoft documentation?

Comment: The same also happens in Chrome and Firefox (tested today). It's a wise decision to avoid XSS scams

Answer (score 1):

Use the Javascript Console (ctrl-shift-j) instead.  It's a much better solution for actually need to execute script.